# How to connect 'localhost' in Iterm2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, iterm2

How are you doing? I am working on, actually learning how to use Ruby on rails. And I've faced seemingly pretty easy one problem, which is connecting Localhost in Iterm(terminal) on Mac.

Since I've been using ROR on AWS server and edited code using Vi, I found it really hard and figured that it would be much better if I work on my localhost server (Bitnami MAMP) and Atom. Unfortunately, What made me stop is I don't even know how to connect localhost on Iterm2. I thought the way I did on AWS (ssh -i abcdefg.pem ec2-user@11.11.111.111) would work, but I don't know what code I should put. Please help me out!!

Comment: Your `iTerm2` shell *is* `localhost`. There is nothing to connect.

Comment: Thanks. But when I type 'ls' in Iterm2, it shows all those contents in 'Home' folder in my mac. 

On the other hand, what I can see 'localhost:8080' in Chrome is 'index.html' file saying what it is about 'bitnami' (located in 'Application - mampstack-5.4.34-0 - apache2 - htdocs' ). And I figured that virtual server is newly made in 'Htdocs folder', which I want to connect to. So I can put Ruby, Git and other stuff. 

Is there something I get wrong? actually I am novice programmer, there are some many things left confusing.

Comment: You are simply in a wrong folder, that's all. Just do a `cd` to the correct directory. If you don't know where it is, type `cd` and a space, then drag your `bitnami` folder from Finder to iTerm2, then hit Enter. Try `ls` there.

Comment: You should already have Ruby installed; can't remember about Git. You might want to install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) first so you can install various command-line things simply.

Comment: Wow. It seems to be getting clear to me. I think I got it wrong. I really appreciate it!